# Twitter App not opening for login like facebook for posting

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

I am implementing share on Twitter and its working perfectly. But my problem is if the twitter App was installed in user device then it will not opening that App for login like Facebook login and sharing/posting stuff. In my case when I try to posting and if the Token was not available then it will open the browser application. I have set the Sign In with Twitter in Developer Account I have checked that option but unfortunately somehow it will opening web browser instead of Twitter app for login authentication.

Has anybody try this. Your help will appreciated

Thanks